# Changing attribute in R not possible because of levels

Tags: r, levels

I am trying to change the name of an attribute in my spatial dataset. It is supposed to be an easy alteration, but for some reason it gives me an error message stating 'invalid factor level'. When I select the attribute it returns the correct name besides the message 415 levels. It confuses me what this means but I assume I can change this attribute name in an easy way. Help is much appreciated!

```
mun_neth$GM_NAAM[406]
```

[1] SÃºdwest-FryslÃ¢n
415 Levels: 's-Gravenhage 's-Hertogenbosch Aa en Hunze Aalburg Aalsmeer Aalten ... Zwolle

```
mun_neth$GM_NAAM[406] <- 'test'
```

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 406, value = c(20L, 28L, 32L, 332L, 80L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: I suspect there's a language barrier here: `foo$bar[406]` is an element of a list element, not an attribute. Most likely your `mun_neth$BM_NAAM` is of class `factor` ; you'll have to tell us if that's what you wish it to be.

Comment: This is the original data. And indeed it is of class factor. I have no say in what I wish it to be. But is it not possible to adapt an element of a list of elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
mun_neth$GM_NAAM <- as.factor(replace(as.character(mun_neth$GM_NAAM), 406, "test"))
```

This will convert the values to character strings before replacing. Afterwards, a factor is created.

Comment: you sir are my hero! Thank you very much